# How to stops flickering in high current draw Circuit

Tags: led, voltage-regulator

I have 6v DC circuit that quickly pulses high current LEDs on and off at a fast rate (10ms or less).

When the high current LEDs cycle, the low power 5mm LEDs used for power on indication and voltage monitoring will flicker.  They are directly attached to the battery source. I figure its because of a drop in current from the battery.. ?

Can someone give me a hint as to how I can keep the current from dropping to these 5mm LEDs when the draw goes up as a result of the high current LEDs turning on ?

Will using an Inductor help resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.
Bob

Comment: more capacitors? less battery resistance? show some schematics so we know what you talk about

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDztTC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

try

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbxQ3O.png)</sup>

where the zener voltage is about 1/2 the normal battery voltage.

This is about as simple as it gets. If you don't want the waste of battery power in the zener, you'll need do something more sophisticated, such as a voltage regulator or constant current drive for the LEDs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since this is a low voltage circuit I am trying to be as efficient as possible with the power in my AA cells. Will the zener use a lot of battery power? I have never used one before.

Comment: Current used by the zener depends on the ratio between R1 and R2. The idea is that the zener draws as much current as needed to get the voltage at its cathode to its nominal voltage. You need to dimension the circuit that the zener current is slightly larger than zero at the lowest expected battery voltage under load, so you are wasting energy while the battery voltage is higher. For best efficiency, use a zener voltage not much higher than the 5mm LED forward voltage, so R1 can be bigger and R2 smaller.

Comment: I was afraid of this. You're using a low-voltage source, so it's not much more than the LED forward voltage. This means that it doesn't take much voltage drop due to load current to give your LEDs major problems. Exactly how many AA cells are you using? I hope you're not going to say 2.

Comment: Its not 2..  I use 4 AAs to get me 6 volts due to the use of a micro controller in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid that the battery voltage drops when you increase the current drawn from the battery, although using lithium or good NiMH cells reduces the voltage drop compared to alkaline cells or (the horror!) zinc-carbon cells. No way of cleverly connecting either the small LED or the high-power LED to the battery (using switching regulators, big caps, inductors, whatever) can prevent this load-dependent voltage drop.

If your 6V source is composed of 4 1.5V cells, you should design a circuit that works down to around 4V to make good use of the battery capacity. Nominal capacity of alkaline (and 1.2V NiMH) cells is typically specified when discharging down to 0.9V/cell.

So to solve a problem, you need to find a circuit that powers the small LED with a current that is less dependent on the battery voltage than your current circuit. Depending on your application, solutions include powering everything except the high-power LED from a low-drop 5V or 4.5V regulator, using a series regulator like suggested by WhatRoughBeast, or using a constant-current-source for the 5mm LED (e.g. the well-known 2-transistor circuit, or a FET in its saturation region).

Comment: Thank you to all that have provided information. It's much appreciated.

Comment: I am using a LM78L05 to front end my Micro. Would this be a sufficient part to help control the voltage drop that occurs to the small LEDs?

Comment: Using a LM78L05 sounds like a bad idea for your application. It requires an input voltage that is at least 1.5V above the output voltage, so at least 6.5V for a 5V output. Even the low-drop regulator LT1117 (or one of its many clones) require at least 0.8V higher input than the input voltage. At 6V nominal voltage you have virtually no reserve. If the LED is already supplied by a voltage generated by the LM78L05, the "flickering" is the proof that your input voltage is insufficient. Also, don't put high-power LEDs behind the LM7805 - you likely overload it.